# what is joint effort?

Tags: microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking at the realtime joint controller tutorial, and it's talking about "commanded effort" for controlling the joint. What exactly is "effort"? It's not defined anywhere that I see. It looks just like some kind of position displacement.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36840/what-is-joint-effort?/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The term 'effort' is used to describe either the force of a prismatic joint or the torque of a rotational joint. It's used to generalize the name for this two types of joints.

---

Originally posted by [Koubi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1680/koubi/) with karma: 116 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10